# Lines within a bar chart equivalent in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api

Is someone able to tell me how to achieve the following tableau vis in power bi please? the line is the previous week and the bar is the currrent. Which chart type do I use?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Next time, provide a data sample if you can. It doesn't need to be much. Like this for example:

```
Day,ThisWeek,PreviousWeek
1,2,2
2,4, 5
3,3
```

I don't think you'll find an exact copy of the Tableau vis in Power BI, but I think a `Line and Stacked column chart` should do the trick:

[image]

Comment: @user3603308, was this not what you were looking for, or did you find another solution?